# Sorting string containing numbers entered from a file in C?

Tags: c, sorting, io

So I'm working on a program that reads lines from a file containing an "item number", "unit price" and "purchase date" for each line / item. I've made it to the point where I can scan the file and organize it in the chart format required, but I can't figure out how to sort the data by "Item number".

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

FILE *fp;

char ch;

fp = fopen("f.txt", "r"); //open the file named f.txt
if (fp == NULL) //In case we can't find the file, notify the user
    printf("File not found\n");

printf("Item \t\tUnit Price\tPurchase Date\n"); //set up the header

while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { //set the character equal to the character next in the file using fgetc, and
                                //if its not equal to the end of file
    if (ch == ',') {
        printf("\t\t"); //add two tabs every time a ',' is encountered.
    }
    else {
        printf("%c",ch); //just display the output from the file
    }
}

fclose(fp); //closes the file

return 0;
}
```

Sample input

[image]

Sample output

[image]

See, I need the output to be sorted by Item number (the far left column).
My idea was to add each line to a string array (char array in c), then from there I don't know how to identify the item number, in order to sort it for the output. I'm slightly familiar with fscanf, but do not know how to apply it here.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: All this code you posted is showing no attempt to approach the problem you are describing.

Comment: Define an array of `struct` each of which holds the three data items of appropriate type. Extract the data from each line of file read with `fgets`. Then use `qsort` with a custom comparison function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). To sort the data, you will need to store it.  That means you'll need more than one character of storage.  You have a problem because `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, and so you either won't detect EOF at all or will misdetect EOF when someone enters a valid character (which might be 'ÿ'). The code shown is not really attempting to solve the problem described; it reads a file and echoes double tabs in place of commas — and adds a heading.

Comment: Store your data in an array, then call `qsort` to sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe it would be nice to break this down into some steps.

1. Define a struct that is specific for your data
2. Read a file line by line
3. For each line, use [strtok()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) to split the string
4. Add these values into your array of struct
5. Use [qsort()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) to sort your array of struct

I highly recommend you read more about strtok() and qsort() functions if you are not familiar with them.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// STEP 1
typedef struct
{
    int item;
    float price;
    char date[50];
} Data;

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{

  Data *dataA = (Data *)a;
  Data *dataB = (Data *)b;

  return ( dataA->item - dataB->item );  // Ascending order
//return ( dataB->item - dataA->item );  // Descending order
}

int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  char line[150];
  Data data[3];
  int i = 0;

  fp = fopen("f.txt", "r");
  while (1)
  {
    // STEP 2
    if (fgets(line,150, fp) == NULL) break;

    // STEP 3-4
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (line,",");
    data[i].item = atoi(pch);  // item part
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    data[i].price = atof(pch); // unit price part
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    strcpy(data[i].date, pch); // purchase date part

    i++;
  }

  printf("##### BEFORE #####\n");
  printf("Item \t\tUnit Price\tPurchase Date\n"); //set up the header
  for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
  {
    printf("%d\t\t%f\t%s", data[k].item, data[k].price, data[k].date);
  }

  // STEP 5
  qsort (data, 3, sizeof(Data), compare);

  printf("\n##### AFTER #####\n");
  printf("Item \t\tUnit Price\tPurchase Date\n"); //set up the header
  for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
  {
    printf("%d\t\t%f\t%s", data[k].item, data[k].price, data[k].date);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that this code is written for your test case only. If your data structure is different (if you have more than three columns etc.) you need to modify the code. Also, you are gonna need to do some more error-handling.

Here is the output:

```
##### BEFORE #####
Item        Unit Price  Purchase Date
583         13.500000   10/24/2005
3912        599.989990  7/27/2008
12          19.990000   3/16/2001

##### AFTER #####
Item        Unit Price  Purchase Date
12          19.990000   3/16/2001
583         13.500000   10/24/2005
3912        599.989990  7/27/2008
```

Hope this helps.

Baris

Comment: Thank you!! Okay, I'm going to read some comprehensive lessons on qsort() and strtok(), so that I can fully understand how to implement this in the future. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Yukut one more thing: I read a lot about strtok and struct usage, I was wondering why I can't just set data[i].date = pch (instead of using strcpy to copy the string held by pch) to the string in data[i].date. Thanks

Comment: @dave99collins Because an array name is not a modifiable lvalue. Just try it and you should get an error.  Note that "date" is also an array (look at the declaration in the struct). Therefore, date = pch is not possible.

Comment: Thank again, makes sense.